# validating whether textfield value is same as one in session (without accessing session in model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am implementing something like an e signature.

User fills a form in multiple steps (I keep storing information in the session) and in the last step I save the form.  However, on the last steps I've added a `textfield` in which the user should enter their name.  The name they enter in this `textfield` must match the one in  `session[:fullname]` or the validation should fail.

What is the best way to achieve this? I want to avoid accessing session inside the model.

Comment: maybe model is exactly where it fits? http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model

Comment: I'm going by this, frowning on accessing session inside the model: http://m.onkey.org/how-to-access-session-cookies-params-request-in-model

Answer (score 0):

So how do you get it into session in first place?

if you do it in controller then pass the value to model from controller :D

Looks like you got the solution on your own.

Comment: I'm close ... :). can a value be passed to a `validate` method from the controller? `def validate(namefromsession) if signature != namefromsessionerrors.add(:signature, "not same") end` guess i should try that.